# how to create tag text box like html tag (in ms access form)

Tags: vba, ms-access, tags

how can create a tag text box in ms access form ?

like that below :

[like this photo!!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ph8ID.png)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a class, something like this.  It would need some work doing, but this is where i'd start.  You cant add controls when not in design mode, so the dynamic solution you expect, probably isn't possible.

A class called `clsTagTextbox`

```
Option Explicit

Private WithEvents tb As TextBox
Private lbl As Label
Private dicTags As Scripting.Dictionary

Public Function Initialise(tbTagTextBoxElement As TextBox, _
                            lblLabelForTags As Label)

    Set tb = tbTagTextBoxElement
    Set lbl = lblLabelForTags
    Set dicTags = New Scripting.Dictionary

End Function

Private Sub tb_Exit(Cancel As Integer)
    If Not dicTags.Exists(tb.Text) Then
        dicTags.Add tb.Text, dicTags.Count
        lbl.Caption = Join(dicTags.Keys(), ",")
    End If
    tb.Text = ""
End Sub
```

And then in your form, you have a label and a text box, mine were `txtTagBox` and `lblTags` and I had the code

```
Private c As clsTagTextbox

Private Sub Form_Load()
    Set c = New clsTagTextbox
    c.Initialise Me.txtTagBox, Me.lblTags
End Sub
```

Comment: Ok, it worked for me, i'll leave you to it.  Any sharing on the error??

Comment: You need to add the scripting run time reference.  Google how to add a reference.